# CSS - Can't send div to the right?

Tags: css, html

I'm trying to send a div block to the right side of my page with a float:right; but it doesn't work.

HTML :

```
    <div id="footer_div">
<footer>

<div class="copyrights">
<a href="contact.html" style="
    color:#8C8C8C;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-size:xx-small;
"><center>Site © 2013</center></a>
</div>  


<div class="footer_links">
<a href="cgu.html" style="
    color:#FFF;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-size:xx-small;
">Conditions d'utilisation</a>
<a href="about.html" style="
    color:#FFF;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-size:xx-small;
">A propos</a>
<a href="help.html" style="
    color:#FFF;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-size:xx-small;
">Aide</a>
<a href="contact.html" style="
    color:#FFF;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-size:xx-small;
">Contact</a>
</div>

</footer>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
footer
{
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0;
    height:45px;
    width:100%;
    background:url(Templates/footer1.png) repeat-x bottom;
}

.copyrights
{
    float:left;
    position:fixed;
    bottom:17.5px;
    text-decoration:none;
    margin-left:8px;
}

.footer_links
{
    float:right;
    height:20px;
    width:240px;
    position:fixed;
    bottom:17.5px;
    text-decoration:none;
    border:0px solid;
}
```

Any idea how I can solve that ?
I want the .footer_links to go to the right side of my page.

Thanks !
Chris.

Comment: Make a jsfiddle with your code so we can help you better.

Comment: I've created a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wumm/wCMqY/

Comment: Please don't use tags for languages which aren't mentioned in your questions. :)

Answer (score 2):

Take off the position `fixed` you have specified on the `.footer-links` class.

See this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/evqbT) example.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/wCMqY/6/

```
footer
{
position:fixed;
bottom:0;
height:45px;
width:100%;
background:red;
}

.copyrights
 {
float:left;
bottom:17.5px;
text-decoration:none;
margin-left:8px;
}

.footer_links
{
float:right;
height:20px;
width:240px;
text-decoration:none;
border:0px solid;
background:green;
 }
.clear {
clear:both;
}
```

It's the position fixed that's causing you problems

Comment: I added background colors just so I could see where each div was.

Comment: And I added a div with a property of clear:both to make any other content that comes after the two divs floated left and right work.